# how to parse "1.23e-4" to 1.23e-4 javascript

Tags: javascript

I try:

```
Number.parseFloat("1.23e-4").toExponential(2)
```

Result is:

> "1.23e-4"

But I want

> 1.23e-4

Comment: Why isn't the string good enough? If you want to display this, your best bet is a string. If you want to perform mathematical operations, you should have a number but in that case, you shouldn't care how the number is represented.

Comment: @VLAZ The same question I asked, but my chief wants it in that format. I know how stupid is that but I don't have a choice.

Comment: im not sure thats possible.

Comment: I searched every method related to numbers and I found nothing

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia no, it's absolutely not possible. Numbers do not have a format. The environment may choose how to present them but that's it. If any specific formatting is needed, it has to be a string. That's basically the same in most languages. At beast, some offer formatting a number when displaying (e.g., `printf` in C) but format is rarely attached to numeric values.

Comment: `Number.parseFloat("1.23e-4") === 1.23e-4`  <= true

Comment: A number in JavaScript - as in most languages - represents a value without any formatting information. If you have something like `let a = 1.23e-4` this `1.23e-4` in the code is a representation of a value in textual form. This is parsed and then stored in a way that it represents the value the `1.23e-4` stands for. How it is stored depends on the engine/architecture (but it is most likely IEEE 754). So  for `let a = Number.parseFloat("1.23e-4")`, `let b = 1.23e-4` or `let c = 0.000123`, the variables `a`, `b` and `c` hold the exact same information.

Comment: If you want to show a number it a particular format you have to convert it at the moment want to show it in that form.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at JavaScript code or JSON, you see the program or the data structure that those represent in a textual form.

Those are parsed and converted to their actual representations/values.

So if you have this code:

```
let a = Number.parseFloat("1.23e-4")
let b = 1.23e-4
let c = 0.000123
```

Then `1.23e-4`, `0.000123` are textual representations of a number. `"1.23e-4"` is a textural representation of a string (`"` the quotes belong to that representation.)

Both `1.23e-4` and `0.000123` result in the same value representation (which does not hold any formatting information) after those are parsed.

`"1.23e-4"` after being parsed holds the textual content `1.23e-4`.

So `a`, `b` and `c` hold the same value, after parsing and execution are done.

If you want to represent a numeric value in a particular format to display it in some way, you then have to convert that value into a string with the desired formatting using e.g. `.toExponential(2)`.

The `Number.parseFloat("1.23e-4").toExponential(2)` results into a value that holds `1.23e-4` as textual value like `"1.23e-4"` did before.

If you use that string in another sting there are no `"`:

```js
let string = "1.23e-4";
let formatted = Number.parseFloat(string).toExponential(2)

console.log(`the value is: ${formatted} create from that string: ${string}`)
```

Comment: let string = "1.23e-4";

let formatted = Number.parseFloat(string).toExponential(2)

obj = {a: string, b: formatted}

console.log(obj) -> {a: '1.23e-4', b: '1.23e-4'}

But I want {a: '1.23e-4', b: 1.23e-4}

Comment: @YugiOh if you want that `console.log` shows `1.23e-4` as output instead of `0.000123` you then need to write your own logging function. Again, a number does not hold a format. It is up to the function displaying that value (like `console.log`, `JSON.stringify`) to choose the desired format.

Comment: I want to send this like params in PUT/POST request, is it possible?